# Программа для вычисления произведения простых чисел до n

Tags: c#

Я пытался но он не работает так, как нужно
Код прикрепил:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int n, d = 1, m = 0;
                n = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
                for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 2; j < i; j++)
                    {
                        if (i % j ==0)
                        {
                            m ++;
                        }
                        if (m == 0)
                        {
                            d *= i;
                            m = 0;
                        }
                        
                    }
    
                }
                label1.Text = d.ToString();
    
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот простой рабочий вариант

```
for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 2; j <= i; j++)
    {
        if (i % j == 0)
        {
            integerDivisorsNumber++;
        }
    }

    if (integerDivisorsNumber == 1)
    {
        naturalNumbersProduct *= i;
    }

    integerDivisorsNumber = 0;
}
```

Пробегаемся циклом по натуральным числам от 2 до n и подсчитываем для каждого числа i, сколько раз оно разделится без остатка на числа из диапазона от 2 до i. Если один раз, то это простое число. Умножаем его на произведение предыдущих простых чисел. Если мы нашли первое простое число, то умножим его на 1. Соответственно, результирующую переменную инициализируем единицей.

Если интересуют более экзотические способы поиска простых чисел, то интернет Вам в помощь. [Вот](https://habr.com/ru/post/468833/), например